# How does syntax of our language affect our thoughts?

Tags: syntax, grammar, reference-request, cognitive-linguistics

Our language affects the way we perceive the world. I know it is not only because the words that don’t exist in one of the languages may exist in the other ones, but also because of the grammar. We know grammatical gender or having more complex tenses have an effect.
But can anyone give me an example apart from lexical context? For example, could "having the verb at the end of the sentence" affect our thinking system differently from "having the verb after the subject" in different languages?

Are there any studies for this case?

Comment: Welcome to Linguistics! This should help your research: [tag:sapir-whorf-hypothesis]

Comment: @bytebuster Thank you! I haven't found anything about the point I mentioned earlier yet but I will keep looking!